# Unbind/Bind new click event to RoyalSlider Arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below script is first initialising the Royalslider script, before unbinding the default click event on the navigation arrows and replacing them with new click events.

I'm pretty certain the code itself is functional, as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmitrySemenov/9w0r021c/). However, on my development site it just doesn't work. There are no errors in the console and I have tried isolating this script to remove any conflicts with no success.

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.slideshow').royalSlider({
        transitionType:'move',
        options:...
    });

        // Unbind default arrow click event
        $(".rsArrow.rsArrowLeft").off("click"); 
        $(".rsArrow.rsArrowRight").off("click");

        // Bind new functions to click event
        var slider = $('.slideshow').data('royalSlider');
        $(".rsArrow.rsArrowLeft").on("click", function(){
             slider.prev();
        });
        $(".rsArrow.rsArrowRight").on("click", function(){
             slider.next();
        });
        $(".rsArrowDisabled").on("click", function() {
             slider.goTo(0);
        });

});
```

Comment: you are disabling the click event, this does not will fire when clicked anymore.

Comment: But I am also adding a new click event, as you can see in the fiddle this does work?

Comment: Are you adding a listener that means on someone else click in the .rsArrow do a slide.prev or slide.next. The point is that your click event has been disabled.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but do you have any solutions?

Comment: do you could not remove your $(".rsArrow.rsArrowLeft").off("click"); ? why you need that?

Comment: interesting, that does seem to work! I was told by the slider support staff that this was necessary. On the third function, I am trying to target the final arrow in the slider, which has a class of .rsArrowDisabled. I want this to reset to the first slide, but it seems I am having trouble targeting this arrow only, and it is being overidden by the previosu next() function. Any ideas? 

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api

Comment: take a look here http://help.dimsemenov.com/discussions/problems/1825-reset-slider-to-slide-1